# use one text field to search database, then pupulate remaining fields in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm new here, so I hope this makes sense   I am new to PHP and Ajax...so I am quite lost.

I have a MySQL database setup, and several forms created in PHP. I have several text fields on one of the forms, which is supposed to show customer info. The first text (phone #) field is supposed to be a search field ... so I need to query my database once the user finishes entering the phone #, to find the records and populate the remaining fields.

I've tried various ways of doing this...but nothing comes out quite right!  The method which seems to show the most promise is by using the Onblur event to call a php page (using Ajax) which will perform the search.

This *works*, in that I can query the database to find the results .. and have them displayed back.  The trouble is that this page with the data inside is actually displayed in the middle of my first page ...so basically I have one web page displaying inside the other...which is obviously not what I want.

The basic code I have is:

HTML side --

```
    <script>
    function showUser(str) {
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("divider").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                document.getElementById("divider").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "GetCustomer.php?q="+str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
</head>
  <label for="CustPhone">Phone:</label>
  <input type="text" name="CustPhone" id="CustPhone" tabindex="1" onchange="showUser(this.value)" value="<?php  ?>">                   
    <br>
   <div id="divider"></div>

<label for="CustLastName">Last Name:</label>
   <input type="text" name="CustLastName" id="CustLastName" tabindex="2" value="<?php echo $clast;  ?>">
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <label for="CustFirstName">First Name:</label>
   <input type="text" name="CustFirstName" id="CustFirstName" tabindex="3" value="<?php echo $cfirst;  ?>">

   <p>&nbsp;</p>

   <label for="CustAddress1">Address 1:</label>
   <input type="text" name="CustAddress1" id="CustAddress1" tabindex="4" value="<?php echo $caddr1; ?>">

    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <label for="CustAddress2">Address2:</label>
    <input type="text" name="CustAddress2" id="CustAddress2" tabindex="5" value="<?php echo $caddr2; ?>">

    <p>&nbsp;</p>
```

and the PHP --

```
include ("AddEdit.php");
require_once("customer_info.php");

function LoadData()
{
$pn = $_POST['CustPhone'];

if (strlen($Pn) < 10)
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE Phone='$Pn'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $rowinfo = mysql_fetch_array($result); 

    if ($rows > 0)
    {
        $clast = $rowinfo['LastName'];
        $cfirst = $rowinfo['FirstName'];
        $caddr1 = $rowinfo['Address1'];
        $caddr2 = $rowinfo['Address2'];
        $ccity = $rowinfo['City'];
        $cprov = $rowinfo['Province'];
        $cpostal = $rowinfo['Postal'];
    }
}
```

}

Any ideas as to how I can do this without jumping around as much ... or more importantly just show the data on the existing page, rather than showing a smaller version of my entire page within the page ??

Thx!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will recommend to use Jquery Ajax, more simple and easy way for Ajax.
For more details, refer [Jquery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). 
So you can change your Ajax call as follows :

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"GetCustomer.php",
            data: "q="+str,
            success : function(data) {
                //do someting with your data
                }
            }

        });
```

With this you can handle error state as well as display "in progress" bar while the Ajax call is in progress.

In **success** you need to map your data with the fields in form instead of displaying them inside a div. This is the only thing you are missing in your approach. So instead of following line -

```
document.getElementById("divider").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

add JS code to map the data with the fields.

You can use JSON datatype and easily map the data with your forms.

Comment: I had tried using JQUERY as well...but never did mange to get that working at all.  What I have now *almost* works.  It shows the info, but as a page in a page.  When I refresh the browser, it looks about perfect.

I've never worked with JSON before ... so I don't know how that works.  Part of my trouble seems to be that need to bounce from one form to another ...Ajax call to different PHP page -  which does not have access to updating the text boxes; etc.

Answer (score 0):

First, I recommend to use jQuery ajax instead of old ajax.

I Think your result are not in the correct place because you are using "innerHTML" in this line of code

```
document.getElementById("divider").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

so your results will be there.

Comment: I removed the innerHTML from that line; and it no longer displays the page in page ... so that is an improvement, I guess.  BUT, I still need to refresh the page for the data to be visible.